# Events indicating Kali yuga

Tags: kali-yuga

What are few Events/Incidents indicating the starting of kali yuga

How was the Transformation of Dwapara yuga to Kali yuga

Comment: Kali Yug started on the day Duryodhana died, Krishna ruled the earth 30 years since the start of Kaliyug. And the whole story prakshit allocating places in which Kali resides in other place Kali should not come. Like in Gamble, Prostitutes, Have more Golden(Hidden wealth), Criminal (who make the life through killing the others) (Hired kIllers, terrorist and whole list of other criiminals)

Answer (score 2):

Kali Yuga began as soon as Lord Krishna left the Earth, [according](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp155.htm) to the *Vishnu Purana*:

> and on the same day that Hari departed from the earth the powerful
>   dark-bodied Kali age descended

And [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/14/) are the evil-omens king Yudhiṣṭhira experienced when Krishna left the Earth, indicating the start of Kali Yuga, according to the *Srimad Bhagavatam*:

> Text 10: Just see, O man with a tiger’s strength, how many miseries
>   due to celestial influences, earthly reactions and bodily pains — all
>   very dangerous in themselves — are foreboding danger in the near
>   future by deluding our intelligence.
>
> Text 11: The left side of my body — my thighs, arms and eyes — are all
>   quivering again and again. I am having heart palpitations due to fear.
>   All this indicates undesirable happenings.
>
> Text 12: Just see, O Bhīma, how the she-jackal cries at the rising sun
>   and vomits fire, and how the dog barks at me fearlessly.
>
> Text 13: O Bhīmasena, tiger amongst men, now useful animals like cows
>   are passing me on my left side, and lower animals like the asses are
>   circumambulating me. My horses appear to weep upon seeing me.
>
> Text 14: Just see! This pigeon is like a messenger of death. The
>   shrieks of the owls and their rival crows make my heart tremble. It
>   appears that they want to make a void of the whole universe.
>
> Text 15: Just see how the smoke encircles the sky. It appears that the
>   earth and mountains are throbbing. Just hear the cloudless thunder and
>   see the bolts from the blue.
>
> Text 16: The wind blows violently, blasting dust everywhere and
>   creating darkness. Clouds are raining everywhere with bloody
>   disasters.
>
> Text 17: The rays of the sun are declining, and the stars appear to be
>   fighting amongst themselves. Confused living entities appear to be
>   ablaze and weeping.
>
> Text 18: Rivers, tributaries, ponds, reservoirs and the mind are all
>   perturbed. Butter no longer ignites fire. What is this extraordinary
>   time? What is going to happen?
>
> Text 19: The calves do not suck the teats of the cows, nor do the cows
>   give milk. They are standing, crying, tears in their eyes, and the
>   bulls take no pleasure in the pasturing grounds.
>
> Text 20: The Deities seem to be crying in the temple, lamenting and
>   perspiring. They seem about to leave. All the cities, villages, towns,
>   gardens, mines and hermitages are now devoid of beauty and bereft of
>   all happiness. I do not know what sort of calamities are now awaiting
>   us.
>
> Text 21: I think that all these earthly disturbances indicate some
>   greater loss to the good fortune of the world. **The world was fortunate
>   to have been marked with the footprints of the lotus feet of the Lord.
>   These signs indicate that this will no longer be.**

Answer (score 0):

When Krishna left earth (around 3000BC) Kali(demon) started establishing his rule over whole earth.

The Symptoms of Kali-yuga mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam:

> SB 12.2.1 — Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: Then, O King, religion,
>   truthfulness, cleanliness, tolerance, mercy, duration of life,
>   physical strength and memory will all diminish day by day because of
>   the powerful influence of the Age of Kali.
>
> SB 12.2.2 — In Kali-yuga, wealth alone will be considered the sign of
>   a man’s good birth, proper behavior and fine qualities. And law and
>   justice will be applied only on the basis of one’s power.
>
> SB 12.2.3 — Men and women will live together merely because of
>   superficial attraction, and success in business will depend on deceit.
>   Womanliness and manliness will be judged according to one’s expertise
>   in sex, and a man will be known as a brāhmaṇa just by his wearing a
>   thread.
>
> SB 12.2.4 — A person’s spiritual position will be ascertained merely
>   according to external symbols, and on that same basis people will
>   change from one spiritual order to the next. A person’s propriety will
>   be seriously questioned if he does not earn a good living. And one who
>   is very clever at juggling words will be considered a learned scholar.
>
> SB 12.2.5 — A person will be judged unholy if he does not have money,
>   and hypocrisy will be accepted as virtue. Marriage will be arranged
>   simply by verbal agreement, and a person will think he is fit to
>   appear in public if he has merely taken a bath.
>
> SB 12.2.6 — A sacred place will be taken to consist of no more than a
>   reservoir of water located at a distance, and beauty will be thought
>   to depend on one’s hairstyle. Filling the belly will become the goal
>   of life, and one who is audacious will be accepted as truthful. He who
>   can maintain a family will be regarded as an expert man, and the
>   principles of religion will be observed only for the sake of
>   reputation.
>
> SB 12.2.7 — As the earth thus becomes crowded with a corrupt
>   population, whoever among any of the social classes shows himself to
>   be the strongest will gain political power.
>
> SB 12.2.8 — Losing their wives and properties to such avaricious and
>   merciless rulers, who will behave no better than ordinary thieves, the
>   citizens will flee to the mountains and forests.
>
> SB 12.2.9 — Harassed by famine and excessive taxes, people will resort
>   to eating leaves, roots, flesh, wild honey, fruits, flowers and seeds.
>   Struck by drought, they will become completely ruined.
>
> SB 12.2.10 — The citizens will suffer greatly from cold, wind, heat,
>   rain and snow. They will be further tormented by quarrels, hunger,
>   thirst, disease and severe anxiety.
>
> SB 12.2.11 — The maximum duration of life for human beings in
>   Kali-yuga will become fifty years.

Comment: Your answer has lots of speculation on Kali. Such answers are not encouraged here. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: Scientific or speculation is not allowed here. Removed the part of answer speculating various irrelevant things.

Comment: add.....................